# Overriding FactoryBean parameters with BeanFactoryPostProcessor

Tags: spring, factory

I need to override a nested property of an `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` in a classic spring xml context.
Since it is a nested property (the `HibernateProperties` one), I can't use `PropertyOverriderConfigurer`

The solution I have implemented is to load the context without refreshing it and add a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` that retrieves the reference to the `FactoryBean` and change the property according to my requirement. However, the result is not what I have expected. It looks like the `FactoryBean` created the `Bean` before the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` is executed, and the property is **mutated** on the `FactoryBean` but not on the already existing Bean, which has been created with the old value

Is there a mechanism to programmatically override some `FactoryBean` properties **before** the bean is created? This is the `FactoryBean` generating the problem

```
<bean id="startupSessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>org.jfin.date.Period</value>
        </list>
     </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: can you provide your xml?

Comment: of what? the annotationSessionFactoryBean?

Comment: of spring xml context